# Divide $18xy+1+27x^3-8y^3$ by $1+3x-2y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Divide $18xy+1+27x^3-8y^3$ by $1+3x-2y$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{18xy+1+(3x)^3-(2y)^3}{1+3x-2y}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{18xy+1+(3x-2y)(9x^2+6xy+4y^2)}{1+3x-2y}$

So I feel I'm on the right track. There's a $3x-2y$ in both the numerator and the denominator. Problem is I have no idea how to deal with the $18xy+1$ in the numerator and the $1$ in the denominator. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'd write $u=3x$ and $v=-2y..$ Then it becomes a little easier to read, dividing $-3uv+u^3+v^3$ by $u+v+1.$

Comment: $$9 x^2+x (6 y-3)+4 y^2+2 y+1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write $u=3x$ and $v=-2y.$ Then it becomes a little easier to read, dividing $-3uv+1+u^3+v^3$ by $u+v+1.$

$$u^3+v^3=(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2)=(u+v+1)(u^2-uv+v^2)-(u^2-uv+v^2)$$

So:

$$\begin{align}u^3+v^3-3uv+1&=(u+v+1)(u^2-uv+v^2)-(u+v)^2+1\\
&=(u+v+1)(u^2-uv+v
^2)-(u+v+1)^2+2(u+v+1)-1+1\\
&=(u+v+1)\left(u^2-uv+v^2-(u+v+1)+2\right) \\
&=(u+v+1)\left(u^2-uv+v^2-u-v+1\right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

I first had the same idea as @ThomasAndrews, but then "improved" it a little (?), letting $u=3x,$ $z=1+3x-2y:$

$$\begin{align}18xy+1+27x^3-8y^3&=3u(1+u-z)+1+u^3-(1+u-z)^3\\
&=z\left(3u+3-3z+3u^2-3uz+z^2\right)\\
&=z\left(9x^2+4y^2+6xy-3x+2y+1\right),
\end{align}
$$

and was glad to find the same quotient as in @DavidG.Stork 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

$27x^3-8y^3+18xy+1=(3x)^3-(2y)^3+18xy+1=$

$=(3x-2y)^3+18xy(3x-2y)+18xy+1=$

$=(3x-2y)^3+1+18xy(3x-2y+1)=$

$=(3x-2y+1)((3x-2y)^2-(3x-2y)+1)+18xy(3x-2y+1)=$

$=(3x-2y+1)((3x-2y)^2-(3x-2y)+1+18xy)=$

$=(3x-2y+1)(9x^2+4y^2+6xy-3x+2y+1)$

By applying:

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)^3+3ab(a-b)$

and

$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$